# How to redirect the user to another page after successfully signing in or signing up in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm looking to redirect the user to another page after successfully signing in or signing up in HTML and Firebase.

I have `login.html` and `signup.html` as well as `home.html` inside the home folder.

After successfully signing in or signing up, I need to redirect the user to `home.html` as well as prevent the user from returning to `login.html` or `signup.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect with JavaScript:

```js
window.location = 'mysite';
```

Redirect in HTML's [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element:

```html
<input type="submit" target="mysite" value="Sign in"/>
```

Redirect in HTML's [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) element:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time; URL=new_url" />
```

Redirect in PHP:

```php
<?php
header('Location: mysite');
exit;
?>
```

Redirect in Firebase:

```
"hosting":{
   "/bar""for requests to""/foo""(but not""/foo/**"")""redirects":[
      {
         "source":"/foo",
         "destination":"/bar",
         "type":301
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside HTML's [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element, use [`<input>` element of type `submit` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) with the target URL.

Here is an example:

```html
<input type="submit" target="mysite.com">Sign in!</input>
```